# Entity Framework - Two projects, same database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, identity

I have two projects in my solution, and they both reference to the **same database**.
Using ASP.NET Core EF & Identity I am connecting to that same DB to store all my IdentityServer information.

## Project IdentityServer

```
namespace IdentityServer.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {}
    }
}
```

## Project IdentityServerBackOffice

```
namespace IdentityServerBackOffice.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {}

        public DbSet<PasswordPolicy> PasswordPolicy { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PasswordHistory> PasswordHistory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I want to generate the database using EF, I get the error that some tables exists, since they were created by the first database-update

## Generating Migrations + Database for IdentityServer

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/ConfigurationDb
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerIdentity -c ApplicationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/Identity

dotnet ef database update -c ApplicationDbContext
```

## Generating Migrations + Database for IdentityServer

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerIdentity -c ApplicationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServerBackOffice/Identity

dotnet ef database update -c ApplicationDbContext
```

There are some common tables shared by both, some specific created for **IdentityServer** and some others for **IdentityServerBackOffice**, how can I ignore the creation for some tables? Or any other suggestion so I can have the DB with all the tables I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the creation of the tables removing his DbSet.

Comment: I have no control on the DbSets for Identity, it is an imported lib. I can only add new ones like I did for the PasswordPolicy and PasswordHistory.

Comment: Any reason for you extend the ApplicationDbContext from IdentityDbContext in IdentityServerBackOffice? try extend from DbContext, the problem of the tables already exist is because of that.

Comment: In the IdentityServerBackOffice (ISBO) I want to have access to the same users as the IdentityServer, so yes. In my understanding, I need to extend it so I can query the same users on both projects. ISBO creates users, IS accesses those same users for Login purposes.

Comment: If you want to have access to users, one of the solutions is creake fake foreign keys to IdentityDbContext. If you extend the IdentityDbContext you  ill allways create his model twice, since you cant change the base model of Identity.